# How to remove email in dektrium/yii2-user?

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

I'm using the module project [dektrium/yii2-user](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user) It has the functionality to login via social network, but from the social network e-mail. Often it is social. The network does not give (or not specified in the profile) and then the module prompts the user to enter the email yourself.
Is it possible to disable an email request from this module?

Comment: update your question and show the related  code

Comment: @scaisEdge this authorization module for yii2, what is the code?

Comment: should be in vendor/dektrium ... somewhere